# Moving Average LOOKBACK

Tags: pine-script, highlight, moving-average

Does anyone know how to write code that highlights the beginning candle of a "X" moving average? For example, using a 50MA, the indicator would look back and highlight the 50th candle from the current candle using any timeframe. This would help to make assumptions of future MA movement without using "DATE RANGE". Also, can the indicator include multiple inputs for multiple MAs?

I don't know how to write code.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a vertical line on `bar_index - 50`th bar.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

bar_offset = 50

l = line.new(bar_index - bar_offset, close[bar_offset], bar_index - bar_offset, close[bar_offset] + syminfo.mintick, style=line.style_dashed, color=color.white, extend=extend.both)
line.delete(l[1])
```

[image]